# Quadratic expression and equations from additional mathematics

Tags: functions, quadratics, conic-sections

Show that the line $x+ y = q$ will intersect the curve $x^2-2x+2y^2=3$ in two distinct points where $q^2<2q+5$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Do you know how to determine when a quadratic in $x$ has two distinct real roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want the curve to be in simpler terms. So we will sub in for $y$:
$$x+y=q$$
$$y=q-x$$
Plugging into curve equation:
$$x^2-2x+2(q-x)^2=3$$
$$x^2-2x+2(q^2-2xq+x^2)=3$$
$$x^2-2x+2q^2-4xq+2x^2=3$$
$$3x^2-(2+4q)x+(2q^2-3)=0$$

Use the discriminant to find how many intersections there will be. For 2 real intersections:
$${b^2-4ac}>0$$
Look at the curve equation to find the coefficients.
$${[−(2+4q)]^2-4(3)(2q^2-3)}>0$$
$${(4+16q+16q^2)-12(2q^2-3)}>0$$
$${4+16q+16q^2-24q^2+36}>0$$
$${-8q^2+16q+40}>0$$
Which simplifies to:
$$-q^2+2q+5>0$$
Look at the form you need it in. Just move over.
$$q^2<2q+5$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Plugging $$y=q-x$$ in the equation above we get
$$x^2-2x+2(q^2-2qx+x^2)-3=0$$
so we have to solve
$$3x^2-2x(2q+1)+2q^2-3=0$$
Can you proceed?
The discriminant must be $$(2q+1)^2>6q^2-9$$ this is
$$0>q^2-2q-5$$

Comment: the discriminant is actually given by $4(2q+1)^2-4\times3(2q^2-3)$